# Gurobi : modifying the linear relaxation at each node of the MIP

Tags: gurobi

I'm looking for a solution to change the linear relaxation ran by Gurobi 7.02 at each node of a MIP. 
I want to replace it with another relaxation I have already coded.
So what I want to do is to say "at each node, instead of running your usual linear relaxation, use mine." Does anyone has a clue do to so ?

Comment: What do you mean by "replace it with another relaxation"?  Are you solving a different model? Looking for an alternate solution to the original LP relaxation? Why?

Comment: By default Gurobi use a linear relaxation to derive an upper bound. 
In the model that I want to solve, there are integrety constraints that cannot be relaxed because the solution becomes nuts.
I want to replace the ordinary linear relaxation where all variables are relaxed by a personalized linear relaxation where some variables are not relaxed.